# Search words in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I want to search in PHP array , value are fetched from table;

e.g.
string is a field in table;

string value are :

```
1st Value :- Hello my name is harkesh 
2nd Value :- Last name is Chauhan

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$array[] = $data['string']
}
```

now array is pulling the complete string value but now i want to search for particular words in     `$array[];`

e.g

if i type "    Last name" it should show me 2nd Value "    Last name is Chauhan" and if i type "    name" it should show me both the values as both of them contains "name"

How that can be achieved..Thanks

Comment: using LIKE in the mysql query i probably a better approach

Comment: `if (strpos($data['string'], 'name') !== false) ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use regex with [preg_grep() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to search for the values:

```
print_r(preg_grep('~\bLast name\b~i', $array));
```

> Array
>   (
>       [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) => 2nd Value :- Last name is Chauhan
>   )

`\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html); Used with `i (PCRE_CASELESS)` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

[Test at eval.in](https://eval.in/267783); [SO Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) for more regex info